# Nextcloud Docker install on RPI unsuccessful

Tags: pi-3b+, docker, nextcloud

I'm trying to install NextCloud via Docker on my Raspberry Pi 4. I have one version up and running with self-signed SSL certificates, but for some reason I cannot update that one.

Here the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:

services:
  db:
    image: tobi312/rpi-mariadb:10.3
    restart: always
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud

  app:
    image: nextcloud
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
```

I changed the mariadb image because the official one doesn't run on a RPI. I have a seperate MariaDB container up and running which is being used by NC and other containers. For this test, I want to run everything as instructed in the documentation.

When I go to IP:Port of the new NC container, I get to the install page. I enter the  username and pw of the admin user and hit install. After that, the loading thing just keeps turning. I've waited 40 mins, which is way more than normal and tried multiple times. All files are created in the data folder, so it seems to be working. When I refresh the site and login, it just reloads the login page. On some other tries, it wants me to reset the password, but after entering a password pressing the "reset" button nor enter doesn't do anything.

The debug log of nextcloud seems pretty useless:

```
{"reqId":"67qiXYLgTl3lWf680iI0","level":2,"time":"1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00","remoteAddr":"192.168.178.25","user":"--","app":"no app in context","method":"POST","url":"/index.php","message":"Could not detect any host in https:///data/htaccesstest.txt","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36","version":""}
```

MariaDB log from Portainer:

```
2022-01-16 22:34:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB init process done. Ready for start up.
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.3.31-MariaDB-0+deb10u1) starting as process 1 ...
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --binlog-format work.
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.31 started; log sequence number 1625452; transaction id 20
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220116 22:34:57
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@cc04c2458c59' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2022-01-16 22:34:57 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.3.31-MariaDB-0+deb10u1'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Debian 10
```

The exact same thing happens when I use the seperate MariaDB container. Am I missing something here?